# Run multiple chatbots in telegram [python]

Tags: python, multithreading, rest, telegram, python-telegram-bot

What I want to achieve: I have a table of chatbot tokens that is updated regularly. My goal is to: 
1)Check if a chatbot token is already running on a thread

2)If the token is not running: start a thread

3)If one of the threads is dead for some reason- create a new one with the same token

My problem: I always get "Error while getting Updates: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request;"

I understand that my solution is not suited for running multiple instances of the bots, but I didn't find any other solution for this.

```
# my_threads = {
#     'token1': threading.Thread( name='token1'),
#     'token2': threading.Thread( name='token2')
# }
my_threads = {}

while True:
    for doc in db["admin_chats"].find():  # loop over tokens 
        if doc["token"] not in my_threads.keys():
            new_thread = threading.Thread(target=bot_runner.run, args=(doc,), name=doc["token"])
            my_threads[doc["token"]] = new_thread
            new_thread.daemon = True
            new_thread.start()

            print "created thread " + doc["token"]
    for key, thread in my_threads.iteritems():
        if not thread.is_alive():
            doc = dict()
            doc["token"] = key
            new_thread = threading.Thread(target=bot_runner.run, args=(doc,), name=doc["token"])
            new_thread.start()
            my_threads[doc["token"]] = new_thread
            print "restarted thread " + doc["token"]
            time.sleep(2)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem does NOT underlay in this piece of code, but in `bot_runner.run`. The error: `Error while getting Updates: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request;` happens when your session has not been terminated correctly ([see this](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/550)). What you have to do is to make sure you terminate the sessions before your threads drop dead! In other words: **FIX THE `bot_runner.run` function.**